# 2 identical YAML files but one doesn't display all the information?

Tags: yaml

I'm really puzzled.

When I open the terminal and do: `php symfony doctrine:data-load` having this file in my fixtures directory:

```
JobeetJob:
  job_sensio_labs:
    JobeetCategory: programming
    type:         full-time
    company:      Sensio Labs
    logo:         sensio-labs.gif
    url:          http://www.sensiolabs.com/
    position:     Web Developer
    location:     Paris, France
    description:  |
      You've already developed websites with symfony and you want to work
      with Open-Source technologies. You have a minimum of 3 years
      experience in web development with PHP or Java and you wish to
      participate to development of Web 2.0 sites using the best
      frameworks available.
    how_to_apply: |
      Send your resume to fabien.potencier [at] sensio.com
    is_public:    true
    is_activated: true
    token:        job_sensio_labs
    email:        job@example.com
    expires_at:   '2010-10-10'

  job_extreme_sensio:
    JobeetCategory:  design
    type:         part-time
    company:      Extreme Sensio
    logo:         extreme-sensio.gif
    url:          http://www.extreme-sensio.com/
    position:     Web Designer
    location:     Paris, France
    description:  |
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
      enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in.

      Voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    how_to_apply: |
      Send your resume to fabien.potencier [at] sensio.com
    is_public:    true
    is_activated: true
    token:        job_extreme_sensio
    email:        job@example.com
    expires_at:   '2010-10-10'

  expired_job:
    JobeetCategory: programming
    company:        Sensio Labs
    position:       Web Developer
    location:       Paris, France
    description:    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    how_to_apply:   Send your resume to lorem.ipsum [at] dolor.sit
    is_public:      true
    is_activated:   true
    created_at:     '2005-12-01 00:00:00'
    token:          job_expired
    email:          job@example.com

# Starts at the beginning of the line (no whitespace before)
<?php for ($i = 100; $i <= 130; $i++): ?>
  job_<?php echo $i ?>:
    JobeetCategory: programming
    company:      Company <?php echo $i."\n" ?>
    position:     Web Developer
    location:     Paris, France
    description:  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    how_to_apply: |
      Send your resume to lorem.ipsum [at] company_<?php echo $i ?>.sit
    is_public:    true
    is_activated: true
    token:        job_<?php echo $i."\n" ?>
    email:        job@example.com

<?php endfor ?>
```

Everythings goes fine.

But If I replace it for this one (every cutting and pasting the code without replacing the file):

```
JobeetJob:
  job_sensio_labs:
    JobeetCategory: programming
    type:         full-time
    company:      Sensio Labs
    logo:         sensio-labs.gif
    url:          http://www.sensiolabs.com/
    position:     Web Developer
    location:     Paris, France
    description:  |
      You've already developed websites with symfony and you want to work
      with Open-Source technologies. You have a minimum of 3 years
      experience in web development with PHP or Java and you wish to
      participate to development of Web 2.0 sites using the best
      frameworks available.
    how_to_apply: |
      Send your resume to fabien.potencier [at] sensio.com
    is_public:    true
    is_activated: true
    token:        job_sensio_labs
    email:        job@example.com
    expires_at:   '2009-02-28'

  job_extreme_sensio:
    JobeetCategory:  design
    type:         part-time
    company:      Extreme Sensio
    logo:         extreme-sensio.gif
    url:          http://www.extreme-sensio.com/
    position:     Web Designer
    location:     Paris, France
    description:  |
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do
      eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
      enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
      nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in.

      Voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
      Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    how_to_apply: |
      Send your resume to fabien.potencier [at] sensio.com
    is_public:    true
    is_activated: true
    token:        job_extreme_sensio
    email:        job@example.com
    expires_at:   '2009-01-30'

  expired_job:
    JobeetCategory: programming
    company:        Sensio Labs
    position:       Web Developer
    location:       Paris, France
    description:    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    how_to_apply:   Send your resume to lorem.ipsum [at] dolor.sit
    is_public:      true
    is_activated:   true
    expires_at:     '2005-12-01 00:00:00'
    token:          job_expired
    email:          job@example.com

# Starts at the beginning of the line (no whitespace before)
<?php for ($i = 100; $i <= 130; $i++): ?>
  job_<?php echo $i ?>:
    JobeetCategory: programming
    company:      Company <?php echo $i."\n" ?>
    position:     Web Developer
    location:     Paris, France
    description:  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    how_to_apply: |
      Send your resume to lorem.ipsum [at] company_<?php echo $i ?>.sit
    is_public:    true
    is_activated: true
    token:        job_<?php echo $i."\n" ?>
    email:        job@example.com

<?php endfor; ?>
```

The info in job_extreme_sensio is stored in the database but not displayed in the browser.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these differences significant for you?

```
--- php1    2010-08-11 16:02:28.000000000 +0200
+++ php2    2010-08-11 16:02:57.000000000 +0200
@@ -19,7 +19,7 @@
     is_activated: true
     token:        job_sensio_labs
     email:        job@example.com
-    expires_at:   '2010-10-10'
+    expires_at:   '2009-02-28'

   job_extreme_sensio:
     JobeetCategory:  design
@@ -45,7 +45,7 @@
     is_activated: true
     token:        job_extreme_sensio
     email:        job@example.com
-    expires_at:   '2010-10-10'
+    expires_at:   '2009-01-30'

   expired_job:
     JobeetCategory: programming
@@ -56,7 +56,7 @@
     how_to_apply:   Send your resume to lorem.ipsum [at] dolor.sit
     is_public:      true
     is_activated:   true
-    created_at:     '2005-12-01 00:00:00'
+    expires_at:     '2005-12-01 00:00:00'
     token:          job_expired
     email:          job@example.com

@@ -75,4 +75,4 @@
     token:        job_<?php echo $i."\n" ?>
     email:        job@example.com

-<?php endfor ?>
+<?php endfor; ?>
```